# CakePHP with large, rapidly growing models

Tags: php, cakephp

Having spent 9 months in a small team developing with CakePHP we are starting to see more and more models becoming 3000, 4000, even 5000 lines long.
Its not that code is being repeated its simply that we are adding a lot of functionality and simply require this much code.

I Know that these files may not be considered to be very large compared to many big apps, and we are certainly lowering the amount of available calls through the use of private functions, however if we want to begin breaking some of these files down to increase manageability, are there any particular techniques that should be followed?

Is it breaking conventions to have models without any db table?
Is there somewhere more suitable for placing large chunks of code?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to answer that properly without knowing the code. Review your code, does the same workflow repeat? Can you abstract it and make it a behaviour?

There is nothing wrong with having a 10k line model as long as the code there really belongs into the model. Rule of thumb: If its manipulating something it goes into the model.

But I would not recommend to use a lot of private methods, they just make testing (if you do unit test - and you should do it) harder, see http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html. The way you use them is wrong in any way IMHO, the visibility scope is not thought to limiting the amount of public callable methods but thought to avoid people extending critical parts of your code for example. There should be in fact not much private methods and those who are private should be private for a very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

you could try looking through everything and evaluating its relevance and whether that functionality is specific to that model or can it be used by multiple models. If you are doing a lot of processing on the data to get into a suitable format (eg. string formatting, date formatting) before passing it back to the controller then some of the processing could be put in to helper files storing generic functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would question whether your models are actually modelling a business object or just a bit of functionality or process.

For reusable chunks of code that are available in many controllers, I tend to create [components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) that encapsulate that section of business logic.

If that doesn't help break down your 5000 line behemoth, then I'd recommend pushing it into a plugin.